# Way to re-direct a webpage and open another?

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, web

Just wanted to know if there is a code for websites, when, if a hyperlinked picture is clicked on the current webpage - www.idontknow.com (for example). One site opens and one changes page

So i click on a picture on www.idontknow.com/page1

and a new window opens to www.youclickedthispicture.co.uk/troll

**BUT** at the same time as the other window opens, isit possible to get www.idontknow.com/page1 to change to www.idontknow.com/page4 for example

Comment: Have you tried to implement this at all? What did you try? What was the problem? Can you post the source of your attempt?

Comment: Why all the javascript answers? There's no javascript tag here gentlemen.

Comment: @Chris Is it possible with HTML?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, with the `target` attribute, depending on user agent settings, capability, and behavior. Modern Firefox will give you a tab, with the default settings, but that is a user control -- if I disable the option, I get new windows.

Comment: @Chris You didn't got his question

Comment: You may be correct. Yuck. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target` property to open the first link in a new page, and then use document.location to change the URL of the current page.

```
<a href="newpage.html" target="_blank">Open in new page</a>

$("a").click(function(){
  document.location = "newpage.html";
})
```

NOTE: The above function is implementing jQuery. Not sure if you are comfortable with that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Pages that open links simultaneously (including image previews) may use the `target` HTML attribute in combination with javascript `onclick`. First, the href:

Take the following html:

```
<a href="http://www.idontknow.com/some_image.png">
  <img src="http://www.idontknow.com/some_image.png" />
</a>
```

...clicking this image will load the image in the same window. Now, consider:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.idontknow.com/some_image.png">
  <img src="http://www.idontknow.com/some_image.png" />
</a>
```

...clicking this image will open the image (or link) in a new tab or window (depends on the user settings and browser capability).

The javascript to accomplish the simultaneous popups:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.idontknow.com/some_image.png')" href="http://www.idontknow.com/some_other_page.html">
  <img src="http://www.idontknow.com/some_image.png" />
</a>
```

Clicking THAT will direct the current page to `some_other_page.html` AND open the image (or whatever) in a popup.

**Documentation**

- `a` element on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a
- `window.open` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="www.idontknow.com/page4" onclick="window.open('www.youclickedthispicture.co.uk/troll')">Click Here</a>
```